# Compile/referencing error with input and standalone

Tags: bibliographies, errors, input, standalone, compilation-error

I'm trying to break up a large project into chapters, and include all the chapters in a single file that I can compile at the end, using `standalone.sty` to strip the individual files of their preambles. I work on the single chapters, and while doing so uncomment the bibliography commands (see below), and everything works fine. But then when I try to compile `main.tex` I get

```
File ended while scanning use of \sa@gobble. \input{preamble}
```

In my project I actually get a PDF despite the error, but the references are all missing.

Here is a MWE, which won't output a PDF at all.

`preamble.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{article}

% BASIC FUNCTIONALITY

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} %try and remove if possible
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}


\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widecheck}{0}{mathx}{"71}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wideparen}{0}{mathx}{"75}

\def\cs#1{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}




% PAGE FORMATTING

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}



% FONTS AND TEXT FORMATTING

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbbm}{bbold}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{AMSb}%
\usepackage{euscript} %to use this font type \EuScript{}, mathcal is left unchanged
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{scalerel} % T_{X_{t_{\scaleto{0}{3pt}}}}M
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\setuptodonotes{linecolor=orange, backgroundcolor=white,
bordercolor=orange, textcolor=black, size=\tiny}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2cm}

\setul{0pt}{0.4pt} 

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\autoreforig\autoref
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoref}{som}{%
    \IfValueT{#2}{[}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \autoreforig*{#3}% 
    }{%
      \autoreforig{#3}%
    }%
    \IfValueT{#2}{,\space#2]}%
  }
}

%This is for matrix spacing
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][\arraystretch]{%
  \edef\arraystretch{#1}%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}}
\makeatother

% SYMBOLS

\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\newcommand\independent{\protect\mathpalette{\protect\independenT}{\perp}}
\def\independenT#1#2{\mathrel{\rlap{$#1#2$}\mkern2mu{#1#2}}}

\newcommand{\scriptbbtau}{\tau \mspace{-9mu} \tau}


\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}
\newcommand{\h}{\mathfrak{h}}
\newcommand{\glap}{{^\g}\!\triangle}
\newcommand{\hlap}{{^\h}\!\triangle}
\newcommand{\gnabla}{{^\g}\nabla}
\newcommand{\hnabla}{{^\h}\nabla}
\usepackage[scr=boondoxo]{mathalfa}
\newcommand{\mathnew}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
\newcommand{\trace}{\operatorname{tr}}
\newcommand{\ddif}{\mathbf{d}}
\newcommand{\edif}{\emph{\dif}}
\newcommand{\bbT}{\mathbb T}
\newcommand{\bbF}{\mathbb F}
\newcommand{\bftau}{\boldsymbol{\tau}}
\newcommand{\bfT}{\boldsymbol T}

\newcommand{\bbP}{\mathbb P}
\newcommand{\bbE}{\mathbb E}
\newcommand{\bbR}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\bbX}{\mathbb X}
\newcommand{\bbY}{\mathbb Y}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\newcommand{\td}{\text{\textdelta}}
\newcommand{\etd}{\emph{\textdelta}}
\newcommand{\bd}{\reflectbox{\text{d}}}
\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{\mathbb{V}ar}}
\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{\mathbb{C}ov}}
\newcommand{\scrS}{\mathscr S}
\newcommand{\bddif}{\text{\reflectbox{$\ddif$}}}
\newcommand{\adif}{{\displaystyle{^{{\raisebox{1pt}{$\scriptstyle \mathscr{a}$}}}}\mspace{-7mu} \dif}}
\newcommand{\difb}{{\displaystyle{^{{\raisebox{1pt}{$\scriptstyle \mathscr{b}$}}}}\mspace{-7mu} \dif}}
\newcommand{\aedif}{{\displaystyle{^{{\raisebox{1pt}{$\scriptstyle \mathscr{a}$}}}}\mspace{-7mu} \emph{\dif}}}
\newcommand{\addif}{{\displaystyle{^{{\raisebox{1pt}{$\scriptstyle \mathscr{a}$}}}}\mspace{-7mu} \ddif}}
\newcommand{\ddifb}{{\displaystyle{^{{\raisebox{1pt}{$\scriptstyle \mathscr{b}$}}}}\mspace{-7mu} \ddif}}
\newcommand{\scra}{\mathscr a}
\newcommand{\scrg}{\mathscr g}
\newcommand{\scrb}{\mathscr b}
\newcommand{\calC}{\mathcal C}
\newcommand{\abbF}{{^\scra\!}\boldsymbol{F}}
\newcommand{\bbbF}{{^\scrb\!}\boldsymbol{F}}



\newcommand{\Xphi}{{^\varphi} \! X}
\newcommand{\Xpsi}{{^\psi} \! X}
\newcommand{\Xth}{{^\vartheta} \! X}
\newcommand{\HFi}{{^{\mathscr F}} \! H}
\newcommand{\HFiv}{{^{\mathscr F} _\text{v}} \! H}
\newcommand{\HFih}{{^{\mathscr F} _\text{h}} \! H}
\newcommand{\HT}{{^{\mathscr T}} \! H}
\newcommand{\HTv}{{^{\mathscr T} _\text{v}} \! H}
\newcommand{\HTh}{{^{\mathscr T} _\text{h}} \! H}


\newcommand{\bfH}{\boldsymbol{H}}
\newcommand{\bfK}{\boldsymbol{K}}
\newcommand{\oH}{\bfH}
\newcommand{\obH}{\overline{\boldsymbol H}}
\newcommand{\bfX}{\mathbf{X}}
\newcommand{\bfY}{\mathbf{Y}}
\newcommand{\bfZ}{\mathbf{Z}}
\newcommand{\gbfX}{{_\text{g} \! }\bfX}
\newcommand{\gbfY}{{_\text{g} \! }\bfY}
\newcommand{\gbbX}{{_\text{g} \! }\mathbb{X}}
\newcommand{\gbbY}{{_\text{g} \! }\mathbb{Y}}

\newcommand{\bfXla}{{^\lambda \!}\mathbf{X}}
\newcommand{\bfXnu}{{^\nu \!}\mathbf{X}}
\newcommand{\bfXmu}{{^\mu \!}\mathbf{X}}

\newcommand{\uX}{\bfX}
\newcommand{\uY}{\bfY}

\newcommand{\Ptr}{/\hspace{-2.5pt}/}
\newcommand{\Aptr}{\setminus\hspace{-2.5pt}\setminus}
\newcommand{\Dev}{\text{\setul{2.35pt}{0.45pt}\ul{$\bigcirc$}}}
\newcommand{\Adev}{\text{\setul{-8.275pt}{0.45pt}\ul{$\bigcirc$}}}


\newcommand{\ptr}[4]{\Ptr^{#2}_{#3} \hspace{-1.5pt}(#1)_{#4}}
\newcommand{\aptr}[4]{{\Aptr^{#2}_{#3}} \hspace{-1.5pt}(#1)_{#4}}
\newcommand{\dev}[4]{\Dev^{#2}_{#3} \hspace{-1.5pt}(#1)_{#4}}
\newcommand{\adev}[4]{\Adev^{#2}_{#3} \hspace{-1.5pt}(#1)_{#4}}


\newsavebox{\overlongequation}
\newenvironment{longequation}
 {\\ \begin{equation*} \begin{lrbox}{\overlongequation}$\displaystyle}
 {$\end{lrbox}\makebox[0pt]{\usebox{\overlongequation}} \end{equation*} \\ }


\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
\newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\bcd}{{\bigcdot}}

\newenvironment{talign}
 {\let\displaystyle\textstyle\align}
 {\endalign}
\newenvironment{talign*}
 {\let\displaystyle\textstyle\csname align*\endcsname}
 {\endalign}

% GRAPHICS

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


% REFERENCING

\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage[pdftex, ocgcolorlinks, colorlinks = true,
linkcolor = ProcessBlue,
citecolor = LimeGreen,
urlcolor = WildStrawberry
]{hyperref}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

%\newcommand{\ppageref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{Page \pageref*{#1}}
%FOR SOME STRANGE REASON THIS MESSES UP THE PAGE-CODE SYNCING... SO WE WILL USE \pageref FOR NOW AND THEN DO A GLOBAL SEARCH AND REPLACE

\addto\extrasenglish{
  \renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}
} % This makes Chapter appear with a capital when referenced

\addto\extrasenglish{
  \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
} % This makes Section appear with a capital when referenced

\usepackage[refpage, intoc]{nomencl}
\def\pagedeclaration#1{\hyperlink{page.#1}{page\nobreakspace#1}}
\makenomenclature




% THEOREMING

% Declare theorem-style environments with \mynewtheorem to maintain just one
% counter for numbering, and make them work with \autoref.
\newtheorem{dummy}{***}[section]
% add [section] for numbering within sections
\newcommand{\mynewtheorem}[2]{
  \newaliascnt{#1}{dummy}
  \newtheorem{#1}[#1]{#2}
  \aliascntresetthe{#1}
  % maybe we will squish some autoref defaults, but who cares?
  \expandafter\def\csname #1autorefname\endcsname{#2}
}

\theoremstyle{plain}
  \mynewtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
  \mynewtheorem{thmdef}{Theorem/Definition}
  \mynewtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
  \mynewtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
  \mynewtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
  \mynewtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}
\theoremstyle{definition}
  \mynewtheorem{defn}{Definition}
  \mynewtheorem{expl}{Example}
  \mynewtheorem{prob}{Problem}
  \mynewtheorem{ques}{Question}
  \mynewtheorem{cond}{Condition}
  \mynewtheorem{conv}{Convention}
  \mynewtheorem{defthm}{Definition/Theorem}
\theoremstyle{remark}
  \mynewtheorem{rem}{Remark}

% COMMANDS

% instead of \defeq and \eqdef use \coloneqq and \eqqcolon (contained in mathtools)

\renewcommand{\dif}{\text{d}}
\newcommand{\diff}[2][{}]{\frac{\dif #1}{\dif #2 }}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\renewcommand{\qed}{\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\quad\qedsymbol}

\let\amsamp=& % use \amsamp instead of & (e.g. in matrices) inside tikz-cd environment

\mathchardef\mhyphen="2D

\binoppenalty=10000
\relpenalty=10000
\sloppy


% Creates colored box with \cfbox{color}
\newcommand{\cfbox}[2]{%
    \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
    {\color{#1}%
    \fbox{\color{currentcolor}#2}}%
}


% The following are macros for parentheses which adjust to size

\mleftright


\newcommand{\T}{\left(}
\newcommand{\TT}{\right)}
\newcommand{\tonde}[1]{\T#1\TT}

\newcommand{\Q}{\left[}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\right]}
\newcommand{\quadre}[1]{\Q#1\QQ}

\newcommand{\G}{\left\{}
\newcommand{\GG}{\right\}}
\newcommand{\graffe}[1]{\G#1\GG}

\newcommand{\A}{\left\lvert}
\renewcommand{\AA}{\right\rvert} %overrides command about accents, watch out!
\newcommand{\assoluto}[1]{\A#1\AA}


\newcommand{\D}{\left\langle}
\newcommand{\DD}{\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\duale}[1]{\D#1\DD}

% TITLE

\title{My title}
\author{My name}
\date{\today}
```

`Ch1.tex`:

```
\input{preamble}

\begin{document}
This is chapter 1, and here is another reference \cite{FH14}.

%\bibliographystyle{alpha} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
%\bibliography{mainRefs}

\end{document}
```

`Ch2.tex`:

```
\input{preamble}

\begin{document}
This is chapter 2, and here is another reference \cite{FV10}.

%\bibliographystyle{alpha} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
%\bibliography{mainRefs}

\end{document}
```

`mainRefs.bib`:

```
@book {FH14,
    AUTHOR = {Friz, Peter K. and Hairer, Martin},
     TITLE = {A course on rough paths},
    SERIES = {Universitext},
      NOTE = {With an introduction to regularity structures},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer, Cham},
      YEAR = {2014},
     PAGES = {xiv+251},
      ISBN = {978-3-319-08331-5; 978-3-319-08332-2},
   MRCLASS = {60-02 (34F05 35R60 60H07 60H10 60H15)},
  MRNUMBER = {3289027},
MRREVIEWER = {Fabrice Baudoin},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-08332-2},
}

@book {FV10,
    AUTHOR = {Friz, Peter K. and Victoir, Nicolas B.},
     TITLE = {Multidimensional stochastic processes as rough paths},
    SERIES = {Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics},
    VOLUME = {120},
      NOTE = {Theory and applications},
 PUBLISHER = {Cambridge University Press, Cambridge},
      YEAR = {2010},
     PAGES = {xiv+656},
      ISBN = {978-0-521-87607-0},
   MRCLASS = {60-02 (34F05 46N30 60F10 60G17 60H07 60H10 60H30)},
  MRNUMBER = {2604669},
MRREVIEWER = {Ren\'{e} L. Schilling},
       DOI = {10.1017/CBO9780511845079},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511845079},
}
```

`main.tex`:

```
\input{preamble}
\usepackage{standalone}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\input{Ch1}
\input{Ch2}

\bibliographystyle{alpha} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\bibliography{mainRefs}

\end{document}
```

I tried to google the error and to do some debugging, but was not able to find what the problem was and would be grateful for any help on the matter. Thank you.

Comment: Normally one breaks up projects using \include and \includeonly for the chapters.  The preamble can stay in the main file.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for your comment. Does this method allow one to compile individual chapters? My understanding was that \include is basically the same as \input, with some minor differences in formatting, so if I \include multiple .tex files that have a preambles of their own it will not compile properly.

Comment: You can only have one preamble, but \includeonly will allow you to work on one chapter at a time (and still use \ref for the other chapters).

Comment: Ok thanks, this is a different approach to the one I adopted, I'll check it out. I preferred to have the individual chapters be fully functioning .tex files in their own right (with their own pdf output and all), but if this is the standard way to handle large projects I will consider adopting it.

Comment: It also keeps track of page numbers.